# # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality key error 0 Python error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the follow data set:

[image]

so as you can see, the shape is: 21 rows x 50 columns

So I would like to apply the follow condition:

If any row from "defaultstore"= 1, then the column "FinalSL" column will receive 4 times the value which "FCST:TOTAL" column contains.

So I create the follow function to do this calculation:

[image]

[image]

What should I do to avoid this kind of error ?

Comment: The error is the follow one:

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2693         # get column
   2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2696 
   2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionalityKeyError: 0

Comment: the main error is so:  KeyError: 0

Comment: [Please don’t post screenshots of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Post the code itself and format it with Markdown.